# How much access does a shell executor of a runner have and can a CI job execute arbitrary code through it?

Tags: security, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am currently investigating the use of local runners with shell executors (`bash`, `powershell`). Usually I would go with containers, however recently I came across a use case, where such an executor has to be used. And this is when I started asking myself "What about security?"

Is it possible to execute arbitrary code in a CI job on a local runner with shell executor? Here I exclude anything that goes beyond what the user, who "owns" the runner", is allowed to do (e.g. on Linux a user, who is not part of the `sudoers`, cannot execute any command that requires `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to execute arbitrary code in a CI job on a local runner with shell executor

Well. CI runners are basically designed exactly for this purpose -- to run whatever code the user tells the CI system to run. So, in that sense: yes, users can execute arbitrary code in the CI job of a local runner. When you configure/install your runner, you will configure a user account under which CI jobs are run. At a *minimum*, this usually includes permissions to read/write/execute files in the build directory, as well as use the shell binary itself. Since CI jobs can write and execute any file they want, that means they can execute any arbitrary code defined by the user.

Whether or not that code being executed is successful depends on what the code is trying to do and the security boundaries you setup for the runner user account. Like you mention, on Linux systems, actions that require `sudo` could be prevented by using a user account that does not have that privilege. There's also a great deal of other security measures that can be taken, not least of which might include using AppArmor/SELinux policies.

Ensuring system security when using a shell runner in a non-disposable environment is a complex and depthy topic, depending on what exactly you're worried about from a threat or system stability perspective. In absence of other specific questions with direct answers, you could consider opening a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions) on the topic to explore it further.

Another thing to consider is whether you *really* need a shell runner or not -- or if that shell runner has to be on the physical host/management system OS. The only cases where I've found shell runners to be (practically) the only option is when physical devices attached to the system are involved that can't reasonably be passed through to a guest VM or container. Almost all other use cases can be met with virtualization, as far as I know. Much like containerization, isolation by virtualization (and disposing of the virtualized environments after a job is complete) helps a lot with a large class of possible threats and stability issues that may arise with shell runners.

Finally, isolation, whether at the container or VM level (or absence thereof), is probably not the only security-related concern that you should have when thinking about your CI runners, especially in a networked environment. A full discussion of runner security involves many layers.